# How to update files without overwriting

Tags: macos, finder

I'm trying to figure out a way to update several text files with new content WITHOUT replacing the original files. Essentially, the files exist on a shared webdav (network drive), and the software reading the files has created generic "permanent links" to the files.

I have copied all of the files (about 600 of them) off the webdav onto my computer and painstakingly updated each and every one of them. But when I copy them back onto the webdav, it breaks the permanent links. Is there any way to do an "update" copy instead of a "replace" copy in os x? That way, the file doesn't get deleted and replaced, and instead just updates the contents of the files?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: No - even if they were ion the same machine you would have to update directly. To see what can be done -   What exactly are the permanent links?

Comment: The permanent links are just a part of the system that reads the files (a windows server). When overwriting it moves the files to the trash, and redirect the 'permanent links' to the file in the trash rather than the newly moved files. Sounds like the only way may be to open each file, copy and replace the contents, and then save again.

Comment: Sounds a bit late for this, but how about trying something like Fetch? I know it's really for ftp & idk how it would work for webdav, but I use it to update remote web pages, without actually 'downloading them'. It does pull the file, but the edit is done 'in place' as far as I can see.

Comment: @Tetsujin as far as webdav is concerned it has to download the file to the client, do any edit on the client and then put the new file back, even though Fetch hodes this from you (I think it also has to lock the file before this and then unlock at the end)

Comment: I thought that might be the case - I guess it doesn't matter for a web page update, no aliases to follow. Sorry it didn't help, wish you luck.